# Acessing referenced entity as a token to use on email notification

Tags: rules, 10

I am using Drupal 10 and Rules module. I have created a rule to trigger when a new content of type "A" is created. That content has a reference to another content type, "B".

I would like the email notification to be able to access both variables as tokens and output something like "Content A was created and it references B".

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give some brief about how emails are triggered like is it trigger by rules or added some custom code for mail , attach some screenshots to display what exactly sent in mail.